# Call socket.io from dgram socket udp4

Tags: json, udp, socket.io, arduino

I'm having some problems with a small aplications that I'm developing.

I have an Arduino with a temperature sensor, I wanted to send the values to a nodejs service, and show it to a webpage. I wanted to use socket.io, but I'm just able to use UDP connection from arduino to server (ethernet). Just to keep the sensor value refreshed, seems that I have to call a io socket from the UDP service, but I can't.

My socket.io that works when I call it from a webpage.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log("Got message: " + message);
    io.sockets.emit('SensorList', { 'temperature': temp });
      });
 });
```

This is the UDP service that reads the arduino packets:

```
 var dgram = require("dgram");
 var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
 var fs = require('fs');
 **var io = require('socket.io');**

 var crlf = new Buffer(2);
 crlf[0] = 0xD; //CR - Carriage return character
 crlf[1] = 0xA; //LF - Line feed character
 server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) { //every time new data arrives do this:
   console.log("server got: " + msg.readUInt16LE(0) + " from " + rinfo.address + ":" + rinfo.port); // you can comment this line out

   **var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
   socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.send(msg.readUInt16LE(0));
   });**

 });

 server.on("listening", function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log("server listening " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
 });

 server.bind(6000); //listen to udp traffic on port 6000
```

The error is: 
     var socket = io.connect('http://localhostit.is:3000');                 ^
     TypeError: Object # has no method 'connect'
         at Socket. (/Users/xfr/Documents/nodejs/temp1/app2.js:15:19)
         at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
         at UDP.onMessage (dgram.js:437:8)

If I erase all the io part, I'm able to see the values in console. 
If there is another way to mix 2 services in one.. tell me some clues and I'll do the search.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Made it!

2  in 1...

```
var http = require('http'),
    dgram = require('dgram'),
    socketio = require('socket.io');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = http.createServer(),
    io = socketio.listen(app),
    socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

var crlf = new Buffer(2);
crlf[0] = 0xD; //CR - Carriage return character
crlf[1] = 0xA; //LF - Line feed character

socket.on('message', function(content, rinfo) {
   console.log('got message', content.readUInt16LE(0), 'from', rinfo.address, rinfo.port);
    io.sockets.emit('udp message', content.readUInt16LE(0)); 

});

socket.bind(6000);
app.listen(8000);
```

On the webpage side:

```
 src="socket.io.min.js" 
 src="jquery.min.js" 
<script> 
var socket = io.connect('http://local_host.com:8000'); 

socket.on('udp message', function(msg) { 
    console.log(msg) ;
    temperature = msg/100;
    $('#temperature h1').html(temperature+'&deg;C');

}); 

</script>
```

bind/listen newbie issues.